# Error authenticating some Adobe packages, how to proceed?

Tags: upgrade

Getting the following message: Error authenticating some packages
This is the list of packages:
acroread
acroread-common
adobe-flash-properties-gtk
adobe-flashplugin

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, and had to manually remove these packages

```
sudo apt-get remove adobe-flash-properties-gtk adobe-flashplugin
```

After this, I was able to complete the upgrade:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Once your system is upgraded, you can worry about getting flash working again, which shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

Hi, you have to install the packages manually.

```
sudo apt-get install namepackage
```

In the list of the packages you have the names!